# Mathematically calculating the fiscal year 5-4-4 schedule

Tags: fiscal

I am trying calculate the fiscal year and return the date when it is the end of a week on the 5-4-4 schedule.

E.g. Fiscal year starts January 1st then I will return the date 5 weeks, 4 weeks, and another 4 weeks.  Then repeat 5 weeks, 4 weeks, 4 weeks until the end of the fiscal year then presumably restart it over again.

How would you mathematically or programmatically go about doing this?

I came up with a subtraction method, but wanted to see if anyone had a better solution:

```
52 - 47 = 5    | February 5th, 2018
52 - 43 = 9    | March 5th, 2018
52 - 39 = 13   | April 2nd, 2018
52 - 34 = 18   | May 7th, 2018
52 - 30 = 22   | June 4th, 2018
52 - 26 = 26   | July 3rd, 2018
52 - 21 = 31   | August 7th, 2018
52 - 17 = 35   | September 4th, 2018
52 - 13 = 39   | October 2nd, 2018
52 - 8  = 44   | November 6th, 2018
52 - 4  = 48   | December 4th, 2018
52 - 0  = 52   | January 1st, 2019
```

Comment: Are you looking for this in any particular language? If you're asking this as a mathematical question, it's probably better suited over on Math.SE rather than here.

Comment: How did you mathematically do it to figure out your sample?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo writing it in C# would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving the issue myself.  Could not find anything on the internet.

Solution:
My algorithm ended up using subtraction in the end but in a modified way from my question.

```cs
int[] pattern = {5, 4, 4}; // The week pattern
DateTime begin = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1);
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Today; // 9-27-2018

// Get the total amount of weeks between the 2 days.  Add 1 for including the end day
var currentWeek = (currentDate.Date.Subtract(beginTime).TotalDays + 1) / 7;
var counter = 0;
while (currentWeek > 0)
{
    if (counter > 2)
    {
        counter = 0;
    }
    currentWeek = currentWeek - pattern[counter];
}    
return currentWeek == 0;
```

This then returns a bool on whether the current date is the end of a time period in the 5-4-4 schedule.  In this case it would return false cause 9-27-2018 is not a day at the end period on the fiscal calendar with a 5-4-4 pattern.